# WPF Datagrid bind additional data from other table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a litte problem with my DataGrid. I bind an observable collection to the grid and define for each column a DataGridTextColumn. This works all correctly.
Now I have an additional list with extra informations about the objects in the existing list (The main list has a foreign key to the other list) and I want to show them in the datagrid too, so I tried to bind a DataGridTextColumn to a property of the other list, so I have there the informations too. But in the column are only the datas from the first object in the list. Is there a possibility to connect the data so there are correct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem but if you have a One-to-One relationship between the two list, you may join the two in a single query and bind the result to the DataGrid